# Typescript generic type issue

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, angular10

I have this code which was working fine in `"typescript": "3.8.3"`
after upgrading to Angular 10 and `"typescript": "4.0.8"` I see some typescript errors:

```html
handleEventResponse<T extends any>(event: CustomEvent, { resolve, reject }): T {
    let response: T = {} as T;
    if (Array.isArray(event.data)) {
      response = event.data as any;
      resolve(response);
    } else {
      Object.assign(response, event.data);
      if (response.status === 'ok') {
        resolve(response);
      } else {
        reject(response.error);
      }
    }

    return response;
}
```

Having these compile errors :

```
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: src/lib/services/custom-events.service.ts:3

362       if (response.status === 'ok') {
                       ~~~~~~
src/lib/services/custom-events.service.ts:365:25 -

365         reject(response.error);
                            ~~~~~
```

Any suggestion to fix it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Your method has a generic type constrained to `any`:

```
handleEventResponse<T extends any>(...) { ... }
```

In [TypeScript 3.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#type-parameters-that-extend-any-no-longer-act-as-any) the following change was introduced:

> #### Type Parameters That Extend `any` No Longer Act as `any`
>
> In previous versions of TypeScript, a type parameter constrained to `any` could be treated as `any`.
>
> ```
> function foo<T extends any>(arg: T) {
>   arg.spfjgerijghoied; // no error!
> }
> ```
>
> This was an oversight, so TypeScript 3.9 takes a more conservative approach and issues an error on these questionable operations.
>
> ```
> function foo<T extends any>(arg: T) {
>  arg.spfjgerijghoied;
>   //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   // Property 'spfjgerijghoied' does not exist on type 'T'.
> }
> ```

This results in `T` being treated as [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown). You cannot do anything with a value typed as `unknown` because it is not type safe. In your code, there's no guarantee that `status` or `error` will be available.

## Solution

You'll need to tell TypeScript that `status` and `error` may be available on type `T`. An example:

```
interface Response {
  status: <your type>;
  error: <your type>;
}

handleEventResponse<T extends Response>(...) { ... }
```